# jQuery conflicts (not in Chrome)

Tags: jquery

I am writing a widget and am depending on jQuery so i need to use the noconflict in order to avoid problems for pages where site owners are also running jQuery.

I have this so far:

```
(function () {

    var js13;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload = scriptLoadHandler;      


function scriptLoadHandler() {
    js13 = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

    main();

}



/******** Main function ********/
function main() {
    js13(document).ready(function ($) {


     main widget code is here.....

} // main

})();
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I am getting (Safari):

```
Type Issue
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.jQuery.noConflict')
```

Need it to work in all browsers, no matter what jQuery or other scripts a page is running.

Another problem is that http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js is not always loading..

I neeed that to load before the rest loads

Comment: Regarding the script that is not always loading: Use the `$.getScript` callback to know when (and if) the script is loaded.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I went in to a meeting. But you can replace the dynamic generation of the script with `$.getScript('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js', function(){ /* script loaded */ })`

Comment: I added an answer with a more detailed example

Answer (score 0):

This will only answer one part of your question, but I couldn't fit it in to the comment box. So, regarding the script issue, one possible solution could be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //couldn't load the script
    },
    success:function(){ 
        //script has loaded, do stuff here
    }
```

});

A possible solution to your other problem could be to simply check if jQuery already is loaded:

```
if(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')
     //jquery is loaded
```